# Multiple postbacks on a CheckBox with AutoPostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I've got a problem with a double post back after a onClick-Event on a CheckBox with AutoPostBack. When I click on a other server control the post back behaves as expected.

CheckBox definition:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCopyToRespDoc" runat="server" Text="<%$ Translation:JacieWeb.Admin.Notifications.CopyToRespDoc %>"
     OnCheckedChanged="chkCopyToRespDoc_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="triggerOverlay" />
```

CodeBehind definition:

```
 protected void chkCopyToRespDoc_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     UpdateRecipients(RecipientsUpdateType.RespDoc);
 }
```

I tried to set the AutoWireUp attribute to false but it only stoped executing the Page_Load event on the first page load.

Did anyone have the same problem or know a solution?

Comment: What is an "UpdateRecipients" function?

Comment: Do you mean when you check the control once `chkCopyToRespDoc_CheckedChanged` is called twice ? Or do you have to call this method only if `Checked==true` (missing the if condition)

Comment: @Vano: The UpdateRecipients function is a own function which handles the update to a database. 
@V4: Yes, exactly. The Event is called twice.

Comment: Did you check for lines registering the handler as i suggested ?

Comment: @V4: Yes I did, there were no such line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself.

I simply have to remove the AutoPostBack property of the check box and the double post back was gone.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkCopyToRespDoc" runat="server" Text="<%$ Translation:JacieWeb.Admin.Notifications.CopyToRespDoc %>"
 OnCheckedChanged="chkCopyToRespDoc_CheckedChanged" CssClass="triggerOverlay" />
```

Thanks for all suggestions.

Greatings

Answer (score 0):

Please use the global aspx option AutoEventWireUp=false.

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="file.aspx.cs" Inherits="Namespace"%>
```

Comment: unfortunately the double postback still exists after I changed AutoEventWireup to false.

Comment: Can you post more code: Page_Load method, aspx header in your original question?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check in case you have registered the `CheckChange` event separately somewhere in your code like

```
chkCopyToRespDoc.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkCopyToRespDoc_CheckedChanged);
```

Maybe in the OnInit or page_Load, you will have to remove the ones since its already registered